# SSRS stored procedure with parameters as dataset not working

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters

In my report i use 3 stored procedures. All of them are using parameters, and 2 of them work perfect and the third one is not, which i really do not understeand.

Stored procedure takes 2 parameters

```
       SPgetData @reportnr,@username
```

The parameter @username is also used by the 2 other SP's

If I call in dataset Query Text then it works, but then I have to specify the parameters by hand like :

```
    SPgetData '001','Administrator'
```

If I try to set Text to

```
   SPgetData @reportNr,@username it opens the screen to enter the values by hand..
```

This is really very strange as 2 other procedures work perfectly with exact the same setup (As Stored Procedure with reportParameters...

This is not a limitation problem of 3 procedures or something because I tested this on a another report.rdl file and it didn't work also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out.

I just need to call the procedure via Text like :

```
   SPgetData @reportNr,@Username
```

then when I get the screen to fill in defaults, I fill in working default values.

On the parameter tab, I attach the report parameters to the query parameters.

When I open the report, it uses the report parameters :)